# How does Python data-frame sub-setting syntactically allow for boolean filtering within a df sub-selection?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, subset

Apologies if this sounds quite basic but I'm trying to understand the deeper mechanics of subsetting syntax:

I understand that with non-.loc subsetting, you can select columns, rows by index number, and cross-select columns and rows-by-index-number.

But by what mechanism do you subset a series of booleans from a dataframe, using non.loc syntax?
e.g.,

Working with this practice df:

[image]

you could write

```
test['age']==42
```

and get a series of booleans indicating where 42 appeared in the age column.

But when you write that same boolean filter as a subset of the same df

```
test[test['age']==42]
```

you get all the columns of the df, and full rows for any row that had 42 in the age column.

I'm wondering, more granularly, by what mechanism you subset a series of booleans from a df in this non-.loc context. Put differently, is this considered a row or column selection, or is it an entirely different mechanism that simply allows inputting a list/series/df of booleans?

It seems like you're selecting whether to show the follow rows depending on the True-False value of each row. And indeed, you could write

```
test[[True, False, True, False, False]]
```

to get the same result. But you'd get an error making the same direct row selection as a list, as via

```
test[[0,1,2,3,4]]
```

At bottom I'm trying to get a better understanding of the mechanism for such boolean-filtering, and how it might relate to non-.loc row/column selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asks:

> by what mechanism do you subset a series of booleans from a dataframe, using non.loc syntax?

The pandas docs on [`Boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) state:

> You may select rows from a DataFrame using a boolean vector the same length as the DataFrame’s index (for example, something derived from one of the columns of the DataFrame)

You also write:

> But you'd get an error making the same direct row selection as a list, as via `test[[0,1,2,3,4]]`

Such error behavior is a result of the fact that `[]` access with a list other than booleans expects column labels, not row index labels. This is made explicit in the [`Basics`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#basics) subsection of the [`Indexing and selecting data`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data) section of the pandas docs:

> You can pass a list of columns to [] to select columns in that order. If a column is not contained in the DataFrame, an exception will be raised.